# What is the best practice to show the data fetched by Laravel 4.2 from Database using 'ng-repeat' of AJS

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I'm fetching data from the database using Laravel 4.2, it returns an array of JSON objects, then I pass that data to a view. But I'm unable to show it using Angular JS' ng-repeat directive. How can I do taht?
Note for Blade I'm using [[ ]], and for Angular JS I'm using {{ }}.
Controller of Laravel is given as Following:

```
class CountryController extends BaseController {
        public function index()
            {
                return View::make('admin.country.show')
                    ->with('countries', Country::all());// returns array of JASON objects
            }

}
```

View of Laravel is given as follows:

```
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-lg-2">Sr.No</th><th>Country</th>
                </tr>
                <!-- foreach($countries as $country) -->

                    <tr ng-repeat="country in $countries">
                        <td class="col-lg-2">{{country.id}}</td><td>{{country.country}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>{{query}}</td></tr>
                <!--endforeach -->
            </table>
            {{countries}}
            [[ $countries]]
```

{{countries}} of ajs not works but [[$countries]] works! How can I access $countries in AJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don'n know that whether it's a good practice or not but I've found the solution which is given as follows:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th class="col-lg-2">Sr.No</th><th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="country in $countries">
        <td class="col-lg-2">{{country.id}}</td><td>{{country.country}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Instead of using

```
<tr ng-repeat="country in $countries">
```

I've used the

```
<?php echo("<tr ng-repeat='country in ". $countries. "'>"); ?>
```

It, after rendering becomes

```
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="country in [{"id":1,"countries":"Pakistan"},{"id":2,"countries":"Saudi Arbia"}]">
```

You can clearly see that an array of JSON object is returned by php, which now can easly be printed.
Note again: I don't know that it's best practice or not! I still would like to know the best practice.